# Unix Script Explaination

Tags: shell, scripting

What is $1 and $2 in below UNIX script?

```
ROOTDIR=/infadata/INFA_SHARED/EDM/MPA
Inbound_PATH=/infadata/INFA_SHARED/EDM/MPA/FTP/InBound
Src_File_PATH=$ROOTDIR/Src
LOGFILE_PATH=$ROOTDIR/Log
CURRENT_DATE_TIME=`date +"%Y%m%d"`_`date +"%H%M%S"`

LOGFILE="$LOGFILE_PATH/Log_MPA_indirect_file_gen_$CURRENT_DATE_TIME"".txt"

INDIRECT_FILE=$Src_File_PATH/$1
Source_FILE=$2
```

Comment: `man bash` or `man $SHELL` might help you, @KrPatel ... it's called *positional parameters*

Answer (score 2):

Those are the [positional parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html), the arguments you give to your script. To illustrate:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "1 is $1"
echo "2 is $2"
$ foo.sh foo bar
1 is foo
2 is bar
```

In general, `$0` is the name of the script itself and `$1`...`$N` are the arguments you give it.